# Run exe relative to current folder

Tags: c#

I have a folder with my exe and a folder called data. How can I access the data folder relative to my exe that is currently open in the same folder as the data folder in C#?

Comment: What is the tag spam for?  This is a C# question.  There is no need mention any of the other tags.

Comment: can you mention the directory structure?

Comment: Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath , "data");

Answer (score 0):

sample folder structure:

```
--ApplicationFolder
       |------> your exe
       |------> Data folder
                 |------> files inside data folder
```

get full paths from relative path

```
string applicationFolderPath =Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

string dataFolderPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Data");
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this heirarchy:

```
/*  bin
       Debug
          Data
              file.txt
          App.exe
*/
```

If you're running `App.exe` and you want to access `file.txt`, you can easily do that using:

```
string str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("data\\file.txt");
```

If your goal is to jump up in the heirarchy:

```
/*  bin
      DataBefore
           file2.txt
      Debug
           App.exe
*/
```

Then you can use:

```
string str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("..\\DataBefore\\file2.txt");
```